# Jquery Button events and form sends not working on setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a table and I have buttons in every row. if I disable setinterval everything works fine but when I start setinterval I only load page any buttons not working.

```
<script src="folder/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#refresh").load(location.href + ' #refresh');
    }, 1000);   

$("#acceptOrderButton").click(function(event){
    clearInterval(refreshId);

    alert ("in");

}); 

});
```

If I disable Set interval and clear interval I see the alert on button click. What can be the problem?

My Button is inside div. So the problem is it. Is there nay way to do it?

```
<body>

<table id="refresh">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="acceptOrderButton">click</button>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Weird code = weird result. Read how does `load` works.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working demo

```js
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#refresh").load(location.href + ' #refresh');
    }, 1000);   

$("#acceptOrderButton").click(function(event){
    alert ("in");
    clearInterval(refreshId);

} );
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<h1 id="acceptOrderButton">
acceptOrderButton
</h1>
```

Comment: Not working for me. I think I need to check all project